# echo ec2 instance id after build in codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to automate deploying infrastructure for an application using codebuild/codecommit. My first task is to create an ec2 instance which I was able to do with running ansible in my codebuild.yml to deploy a using template in s3 bucket. Next I want to deploy some configuration file onto that instance that are stored in s3. How do I get IP/hostname of that instance to use it in ansible and push those config files??

Comment: Are you using CloudFormation or terraform for your infrastructure definitions?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want.

If you want to resort to Ansible probably the best option would be to use [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) and output the IP of the instance you have created to it. You can then re-use it within the playbook as it's available as a variable.

Another option is to use dynamic inventory and get the IP of the instance you have created in a subsequent play (second codebuild job) by using [dynamic inventory and filter by tag](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html)

Comment: Thanks Nick, I was able to accomplish my task using dynamic inventory. Appreciate the help.